# Use pgbackups dump to selectively restore to heroku db

Tags: heroku, rails-postgresql, pg, heroku-postgres

I have a dump filed generated from pgbackups and I want to use some of the data in it to populate a new database on heroku. It's not a simple restore.

I want to use the `-t` option from `pg_restore` and also want to map the `from` attribute from `emails` table of dump to `from_email` attribute in the new `emails` table.

I don't have the `pg_restore` utility in heroku run bash, but is there a way to get that or do this through `psql`? Heroku's db structure seems to be broken up in some way, I don't know how to mess around in `psql`.

Comment: What format did you use, when you created the backup? (plain, custom,directory,tar)

Comment: If you can do `pg_dump` again, you can use `-t` with `pg_dump`. After - just restore it.

Comment: I used `curl -o latest.dump `heroku pgbackups:url` get the dump. The `pgbackups` addon doesn't have a `-t` option?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can remap column names quite like this.  I think your best option is to restore the table as it exists and then alter it to change the column name.  If you are adding to an existing table, restore it into a different schema and then `INSERT ... SELECT ...`

If that fails, you could restore into a new db, remap, and then dump again.